# grouping in codeigniter sql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, group-by

I want to group data by 2 grouping , as a column and a row
`Sample input`:
[image: Sample Input Table]
`Expected output Example` :

```
               2017-02-16       2017-02-17     2017-02-18
Doctor Name 1   available      available      not available
Doctor Name 2   available      not available  not available
Doctor Name 3   available      not available  available
```

Currently my output is not working for the doctors who are available more than one date.

Comment: Please provide the sample input data from which you want to build this output

Comment: Doctor ID  Available Date    Appointment no

Doctor name 1          2017-02-16         1
Doctor name 1          2017-02-16         2
Doctor name 1          2017-02-16         3
Doctor name 1          2017-02-17         1
Doctor name 2          2017-02-16         1
Doctor name 3          2017-02-16         1
Doctor name 3          2017-02-18         2

Comment: Please provide sample input table

Comment: Doctor ID          Available Date Appointment no
Doctor name 1    2017-02-16        1
Doctor name 1    2017-02-16        2
Doctor name 1    2017-02-16        3
Doctor name 1    2017-02-17       1
Doctor name 2    2017-02-16       1
Doctor name 3    2017-02-16       1
Doctor name 3    2017-02-18       2

Comment: Please update question with table schema and sample data